# filebase plugin in wordpress doesn't load the files in treeview

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using wp-filebase for managing the files on wordpress. The problem is that it doesn't load the files anumore and in console I get the error message:

```
POST http://.../wp-content/plugins/filebase/wpfb-ajax.php 200 OK
a is null

f(a=null, c=createNode(parent), d=[[ul]])jquery...r=1.7.1 (riga 2)
  success(response=null)jquery....2.9.14 (riga 50)
f(b=Object { url="http://gliamicidipooh.i...-filebase/wpfb-ajax.php", isLocal=false,    global=true, altri elementi...}, f=[null, "success", Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="OK"}])jquery...r=1.7.1 (riga 2)
f(b=Object { url="http://gliamicidipooh.i...-filebase/wpfb-ajax.php", isLocal=false, global=true, altri elementi...}, c=[null, "success", Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="OK"}])jquery...r=1.7.1 (riga 2)
clone(a=200, c="OK", l=Object { text=""}, m="Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2012 ...sfer-Encoding: chunked\n")jquery...r=1.7.1 (riga 4)
clone(a=readystatechange , e=undefined)jquery...r=1.7.1 (riga 4)
[Interrompi per questo errore]  

..."resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b...
```

Can it be problem with jQuery version? I am using filebase v. 0.2.9.14 on wordpress 3.3.1. If you need additional information please leave a comment and I will edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was that I was using a gzip compression plugin and it was causing this problem. After disabling the compression it works fine.